# Can one (more or less) automatically suppress ligatures for certain words?

Tags: luatex, typography, context, ligatures

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`selnolig`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/selnolig)

One of the major attractions -- for me at least -- of typesetting my papers in (La)TeX is its automated and fully transparent use of typographic ligatures. However, as Knuth pointed out in the TeXbook, it is sometimes necessary to disable or suppress ligatures in order to either improve a word's legibility (Knuth uses the word `shelfful` as an example) or so as not to inadvertently change its meaning, which is especially important in some non-English European languages, such as German, which have lots of compound words (viz., `Sauf{}laden` vs. `Sau{}fladen`, and `Chef{}innenleben` vs. `Chefinnen{}leben`).

Here's my question, which is related to a question I posed in comp.text.tex about half a year ago but which didn't generate any good answers: If one were to compile a list of words for which ligatures should be suppressed, is there a way to program TeX (possibly/likely LuaTeX) not to use ligatures for these words? Please note that I am **not** looking to suppress ligatures globally for the entire document, but only those that occur in certain words.

Suppose one had a list of words such as

```
shelf{}ful, self{}ish, self{}less, half{}life, shelf{}life, dwarf{}like, 
waif{}like, wolf{}like, half{}line, roof{}line, Pfaff{}ian, cuff{}link, 
off{}load, off{}line, wolf{}fish, chaf{}finch, saf{}flower
```

Is there a way to pass this list to TeX and to instruct it to either not insert a ligature at all (as in `shelfful` and `shelflife`) or to use only a two-character rather than a three-character ligature (for `Pfaffian` and `offline`, say)? Possibly, this *no-ligation* list would also indicate to TeX the method by which the ligation should be suppressed. To suppress a ligature, one can insert a pair of braces, `{}`, an italics correction, `\/`, or a zero-width kern, `\kern0pt`. However, these methods do not in general produce the same outcome, especially in the case of the `fl` character pair, and it may therefore be desirable to instruct TeX exactly which non-ligation method it should employ when it encounters a word on the no-ligation list.

By the way, observe that the no-ligation instances for all words in the above list correspond to potential hyphenation points. A pure guess on my part: a solution to the challenge I'm posing may involve creating two types of hyphenation points: the first type would consist of "ordinary" hyphenation points, and instances of the second type would inform TeX that it's dealing with both a hyphenation point and a no-ligation point.

Addendum 16 September -- I've added a "bounty" of 200 points. :-)

## And the winning answer is...

I've declared Aditya's entry below the winner. Here's a modified version of his MWE, which contains a (very!!) contrived sentence that contains words with seven different types of ligatures that should be suppressed (f-f, f-i, f-l; ff-i, ff-l; f-fi, and f-fl). Observe that the MWE needs to be compiled with `ConTeXt`.

```
\usemodule[translate]

\translateinput[shelffuls][shelf|*|fuls]
\translateinput[selfish][self|*|ish]
\translateinput[halflife][half|*|life] 
\translateinput[standoffish][stand|*|off|*|ish]
\translateinput[cufflinks][cuff|*|links] 
\translateinput[offloads][off|*|loads]    
\translateinput[chaffinches][chaf|*|finches]
\translateinput[safflower][saf|*|flower]

\definetextmodediscretionary * {\prewordbreak\discretionary{-}{}{\kern0pt}\prewordbreak}
\hyphenation{chaf-finches}
\starttext

No ligatures disabled:\\
A standoffish and selfish person who offloads shelffuls 
   of cufflinks and doesn't watch chaffinches in the
   safflower field has a short halflife.

\medskip
\enableinputtranslation 
Some, but not all, ligatures disabled:\\
A standoffish and selfish person who offloads shelffuls 
   of cufflinks and doesn't watch chaffinches in the
   safflower field has a short halflife.

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: To prevent ligatures also `"|` as in `Kauf"|leute` should be mentioned. (Which doesn't answer the question how to do so globally, which would be really interesting. Therefore it's just a comment.)

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. Just out of curiosity: how does the output of the `"|` method of suppressing ligatures compare with that of the `{}` and `\/` methods?

Comment: `"|` is `babel`'s command to suppress a ligature in _some_ languages, cf. my comment to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19263/what-are-the-finishing-touches-you-put-to-a-document/19566#19566 and also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27198/babel-adding-ngermans-language-shorthands-to-english-as-the-main-document-la.

Comment: Thanks, @doncherry. I'm familiar with babel's `|"` construct; my question is about the precise form of the ligation suppression operation it performs. Is its output similar to that of TeX's `{}` command or, alternatively, close to that of the `\/` control sequence. My point is that the precise form of the optimal ligation suppression command may vary depending on the character pairs involved.

Comment: The babel `"|` is language dependent. It usually does something like `\textormath{\discretionary{-}{}{\kern.03em}}{}` so it's both a hyphenation point and no-ligation point.

Comment: For `fontspec` I define `\newcommand{\NL}[1]{{\addfontfeature{Ligatures=NoCommon}#1}}` and RegEx the source through before proofreading (`\wf[fli]\w` -> `\\NL{&}`). This is stupid work, but in German texts these combinations aren't too numberous. On the plus side you'll stay in control and using the font-feature retains the font's original kerning for these difficult pairs.

Comment: @Florian -- sorry for the slow follow-up: What do you do with words such as "trefflich"? Ideally, one has to suppress the "ffl" ligation-glyph while not also suppressing the "ff" glyph at the end of the first syllable, right? Won't the `Ligatures=NoCommon` option suppress the latter ligature (the `ff`) as well?

Comment: @mico -- Writing `treff\NL{l}ich` sort-of works: it retains the `ff`-ligature, but not  `ffl`. The problem is, that the kern between `ff` and `l` is ignored. But most fonts don't have a good kerning for this pair anyway, so this might call for a manual `\kern`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In LuaTeX you can intercept the input and change it before TeX sees it. This can be used to disable certain ligatures. Here is a proof of concept in ConTeXt.

```
\usemodule[translate]

\translateinput[selfish][self|*|ish]
\translateinput[halflife][half|*|life]

\starttext

A selfish person has a small halflife.

\enableinputtranslation 

A selfish person has a small halflife.

\disableinputtranslation

A selfish person has a small halflife.

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

See m-translate.mkiv in the ConTeXt distribution for implementation details. Keep in mind that this will change **all** occurrences of "selfish" to "self|*|fish", **including those in csname**. For example, if you have a `selfish` environment, it will fail! The advantage of this approach is that it will work for all words that contain `selfish`; for example, `selfishness`, `unselfish`, etc.

`|*|` disables ligatures and does not affect hyphenation. But it introduces a `0.05em` kern between the two letters. If you do not like that add

```
\definetextmodediscretionary *
  {\prewordbreak\discretionary{-}{}{}\prewordbreak}
```

Comment: @Mico:  The above fragment is a MWE...I guess you mean a MWE in LaTeX :)

Comment: I don't know how TeXworks invokes ConTeXt. Can you simply try to call `context filename` from command line.

Comment: A follow-up question: does the "insertion" of `\null{}` affect the hyphenation of the word? More precisely, will insertion of `\null{}` disable hyphenation?

Comment: @Mica: It does disable hyphenation :( I don't know how to disable ligatures in ConTeXt without disabling hyphenation. A simple `{}` like in `self{}ish` does not work. I'll try to find out.

Comment: @Mica: Use `\zwnj` instead of `\null`. `\zwnj` does not affect hyphenation.

Comment: I can definitely confirm that `\zwnj` disables hyphenation, whether or not inputtranslation is enabled. I'm keeping my fingers crossed that you'll succeed in locating a suitable unicode character that breaks up ligation but doesn't disable hyphenation. :-)

Comment: @Mico: Another option is `\self|*|ish` which does not disable hyphenation between `f` and `i`, but inserts a `0.05em` space. You can get rid of that space by redefining `*` discretionary. The original definition is `\definetextmodediscretionary *{\prewordbreak\discretionary{-}{}{\kern.05em}\prewordbreak}` Change `.05em` to `0pt`.

Comment: @Aditya: And +1 for getting a word of wisdom out of a small list of random words ;-)

Comment: @Aditya. Is `\translateinput` or something similar also accessible from LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @Andy: In principle yes (after all it is built on luatex), but AFAIK no one has ported the corresponding lua code to lualatex.

Comment: @Aditya: Would you happen to know what the `lualatex` equivalent of ConTeXt's `\usemodule` macro is? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mico: `\usemodule` is similar to `\usepackage`. The `translate` module relies on a lua function `resolvers.openers.helpers.textlineactions`, which hooks into the function that luatex uses to read files. AFAIK, no one has written similar functionality for `lualatex`. Perhaps, you could ask it as a separate question, and one of the `lualatex` experts will be able to answer with a solution.

Comment: @Aditya: Great suggestion, will do soon.

Comment: Would it make sense to make a package that would contain a whole library of words for which ligatures need to be changed?

Answer (score 14):

Just today I discovered a [blog-entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20150425155310/http://www.mengensatz.de/blog/?p=79) on this issue. As it turns out there are two ready-to-use different solutions to this problem on CTAN:

- [rmligs](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/rmligs) uses a word-list from Ispell
- [ligatex](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/ligatex) uses a syllable-based approach, not unlike TeX's hyphenation

Both are TeX-independend programs which modify the source before compiling. Both are only for German, but are supposed to be customisable for other languages.

Comment: Thanks for this! Does anyone know if these packages are still maintained and, if so, by whom? More importantly, could anyone share practical experiences with these programs? As written, they're mainly (exclusively?) intended for German documents, and they require the use of `babel` and/or `german`, which makes me a bit concerned about their usability for languages other than German. Anyone wish to comment?

Comment: There is also DeLig - http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/delig/

Comment: Note that these tools do wrong in the case of other fonts: See @Mico: The issue of how much whitespace (if any) should be inserted in order to create a visible gap between "f" and f/i/l is strongly font-dependent. babel's "| method not only breaks up the ligature but also inserts 0.03em of whitespace. This setting seems to have been arrived at for the Computer/Latin Modern Roman font face and, in particular, the f-l ligature case. [...] With Times Roman, in contrast, 0.03em is not sufficient for the f-l case. And, for EB Garamond, one would have to insert 0.11em to create a gap.

Comment: Long comparison about selnolig vs. babel shortcuts: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389439/9075

Answer (score 5):

In case one use LuaLaTeX, you can use the [selnolig](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/new-package-selnolig-that-automates-suppression-of-typographic-ligatures) package. Be aware that one has to use the [fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fontspec) package then.

English:

```
\usepackage[english]{selnolig}
```

German:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{selnolig}
```

More information:

- [New package, selnolig, that automates suppression of typographic ligatures](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/new-package-selnolig-that-automates-suppression-of-typographic-ligatures)
- Explanation of selnolig vs. babels "| shortcut: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389439/9075
- Discussion regarding fontspec and lualatex: [Can we stop recommending fontspec as first choice in case lualatex is used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/338781/9075)

Comment: This nicely comes full circle, because it's the author of this question who later went on to create the `selnolig` package. :-)