# Porting the luatex/ConTeXt module "translate" to lualatex

Tags: luatex, context, ligatures

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28437/can-one-more-or-less-automatically-suppress-ligatures-for-certain-words), which I posted a few weeks ago to TeX Stack Exchange, I asked how one should go about disabling specific ligatures (such as `ff`, `fi`, `fl`, and `ffl`) automatically for a list of pre-defined words. The answer I received was based on ConTeXt, which can access lua(tex) commands directly. In particular, the code that @Aditya came up with includes the commands

```
\usemodule[translate]
\translateinput[halflife][half|*|life]
```

The ConTeXt command `\usemodule` is similar to the LaTeX command `\usepackage`. The `\translateinput` command provided by the `translate` module (which is contained in the file `m-translate.mkiv`) relies on the `lua` function `resolvers.openers.helpers.textlineactions`, which hooks into the function that `luatex` uses to read files. According to @Aditya,

> no one has written similar functionality for `lualatex`. Perhaps, you could ask it as a separate question, and one of the `lualatex` experts will be able to answer with a solution.

Here, then, is my question: Can someone provide the `lualatex` equivalent of the following ConTeXt code (which may involve re-writing/adapting the `translate` module to `lualatex`):

```
\usemodule[translate]

\translateinput[shelfful][shelf|*|ful] 
\translateinput[selfish][self|*|ish]
\translateinput[halflife][half|*|life] 
\translateinput[cufflink][cuff|*|link] 

\definetextmodediscretionary * {\prewordbreak\discretionary{-}{}%
     {\kern0.0pt}\prewordbreak}

\starttext

Ligatures not disabled:\\
shelfful selfish halflife cufflink 

\medskip
\enableinputtranslation 
Ligatures disabled:\\
shelfful selfish halflife cufflink
\stoptext
```

[image]

(Note that while a 0-kern separator seems to be appropriate for the words shelfful and selfish typeset with CM, it's not quite adequate for the `f-l` and `ff-l` ligatures. However, I'll leave the question of how to define commands that allow for distinct kerning amounts for various combinations of ligated letters for a different, future question...)

Comment: Another advantage of such a module (err...I mean package) will be true [block comments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34482/contest-show-off-your-skillz-in-tex-friends-tex-sx-birthday/35017#35017) in LaTeX

Comment: I doubt that is easily possible. It may turn out that this module is too much dependent on ConTeXt itself. The wise thing is that you, yourself devise something independent of ConTeXt.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi: Thanks for this suggestion. Unfortunately, because I'm not (yet) sufficiently familiar with `lua(la)tex` and `ConTeXt`, I can't take you up on it. That's also why I've posted this question in the first place. :-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is more a proof-of-concept than a real bulletproof style file, but it does what you request:

The style file (`filterltx.sty`)

```
\ProvidesPackage{filterltx}
\RequirePackage{luatexbase,luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
do
  local replace = {}

  local filter = function ( buf )
    local start,stop,init,pos
    local positions = {}
    for k,v in pairs(replace) do
      local init = 1
      repeat
        start,stop = string.find(string.lower(buf),k,init,true)
        if start then
          init = stop
          pos = string.find(v,"|*|",1,plain)
          positions[#positions + 1] = pos + start - 2
        end
      until start == nil
    end
      table.sort(positions)
      for i = #positions,1,-1 do
        buf = string.sub(buf,1,positions[i] ) .. [[\penalty10000\discretionary{-}{}{\kern.03em}\nobreak \hskip 0pt plus0pt minus0pt]] .. string.sub(buf, positions[i] + 1)
      end
    return buf
  end

  function enablefilter()
    luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer', filter, 'filter')
  end

  function disablefilter()
    luatexbase.remove_from_callback('process_input_buffer', 'filter')
  end

  function translateinput( arg1,arg2 )
    replace[arg1] = arg2
  end

end
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand\enableinputtranslation{
  \directlua{enablefilter()}
}
\newcommand\disableinputtranslation{
  \directlua{disablefilter()}
}
\newcommand\translateinput[2]{
  \directlua{translateinput("\luatexluaescapestring{#1}","\luatexluaescapestring{#2}")}
}
```

and the test document (`test.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filterltx}

\translateinput{shelfful}{shelf|*|ful} 
\translateinput{selfish}{self|*|ish}
\translateinput{halflife}{half|*|life} 
\translateinput{cufflink}{cuff|*|link}

\begin{document}

Ligatures not disabled:\\
shelfful selfish halflife cufflink 

\medskip
\enableinputtranslation 
Ligatures disabled:\\
shelfful selfish halflife cufflink\\
Shelfful Selfish Halflife Cufflink

\medskip
\disableinputtranslation
Ligatures not disabled:\\
shelfful selfish halflife cufflink 

% to make sure the words still hyphenate:
% \showhyphens{shelfful selfish halflife cufflink}
% yields: shelf- ful self- ish half- life cuff- link
\end{document}
```

Run with `lualatex test`.

The output: [image: filteroutput]

Comment: Thanks for the great code. Unfortunately, it appears to have a rather severe negative side-effect. :-( Specifically, TeX no longer wants to hyphenate the words at the junction points (shelf-ful, self-ish, half-life cuff-link) even though these junction points are valid hyphenation points. May I ask you, somewhat belatedly, to investigate how this problem can be solved?

Comment: @Mico I have edited my answer to fix the broken hyphenation.

Comment: One more question, if you don't mind: Is there a version of lua's `string.gsub` function that's not case-sensitive? More specifically, it should preserve the (upper/lower) caes of letters automatically. An ideal solution would let the command `\translateinput{auflage}{auf|*|lage}` operate on the word `Auflage` as well -- and generate `Auf|*|lage`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mico Done. I have changed the algorithm a bit... Drawback: currently only one ligature per word can be suppressed. The rest is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 13):

The basic functionality is part of luatex. For example, the following code (in luatex plain format) changes "hello" to "hi".

```
\directlua{
  local gsub = string.gsub
  local function translate(line)
      return gsub(line, "hello", "hi")
  end

  callback.register("process_input_buffer", translate)
}

hello world

why say hello
\bye
```

The ConTeXt code just provides syntax sugar so that you can easily define multiple translations. I tried to translate this code to `lualatex` but in lualatex I get an error

```
uatexbase-mcb error: function callback.register has been trapped,
(luatexbase-mcb)             please use luatexbase.add_to_callback instead.

stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    .../share/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/modutils.lua:26: in function 'modul
e_error_int'
    .../share/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/modutils.lua:45: in function 'err'
    /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/mcb.lua:85: in function 'register'

    <\directlua >:7: in main chunk.
\luacode@execute ...oup \luatexbase@directlua {#1}

l.11 \end{luacode}
```

but I could not get the code to work with `luatexbase.add_to_callback` either.

The above plain TeX code shows that basic functionality is part of luatex and should be easily accessible in `lualatex` as well (once you figure out the appropriate renaming done by `luacode` package).