# How can I invoke a macro inside minted inline code?

Tags: minted, inline

How can I use a command inside a `minted` one-liner?

This code

```
\newcommand{\HADOOPUSER}{hduser}
\mint{console}|sudo groupadd \HADOOPUSER|
```

currently produces

> sudo groupadd \HADOOPUSER

whereas the output I want is

> sudo groupadd hduser

Comment: What you want to do is not possible. The only way of invoking a command inside `minted` is via an escape to LaTeX, which is only possible inside comments in the language used. `listings` can do it, though.

Comment: @Jubobs Can you please explain to me the first part, with an escape to LaTex, or maybe point me to an example?

Comment: @Jubobs: Never say never. See my answer.

Comment: @Aditya My understanding is that the OP wants to use `minted` specifically, though.

Comment: @Jubobs: My solution should work with minted + LuaLaTeX using the LaTeX port of `m-translate` (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36021/323)

Comment: @Aditya If you say so. I'm don't know ConTeXt well enough to  be able to tell `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I really enjoy `minted`, I don't think it is the right tool for what you want to do. Invoking macros inside listings typeset by `minted` is currently very limited (as of v1.7). The package does provide an option called `mathescape` for allowing escape to LaTeX (i.e. interpret a sequence of token as LaTeX code instead of verbatim), but

- such an escape to LaTeX is only possible **inside comments in the language being used**,
- that feature is mainly oriented towards content of mathematical nature.

Here is an example adapted from the `minted` manual:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[mathescape]{python}
# Returns $\sum_{i=1}ˆ{n}i$
def sum_from_one_to(n):
    r = range(1, n + 1)
return sum(r)
# An escape to LateX won't work outside comments
$\sum_{i=1}ˆ{n}i$
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Clearly, your shell script is not a comment, so there is no way of getting your macro to expand to its replacement text in your listing.
Actually, what I gather from the [Python source](https://pygments-doc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lexers/shell.html) of the lexer you use, `console` (a.k.a. `BashSessionLexer`), is that it doesn't define shell to-end-of-line comments (started by a `#`). Therefore, you can't even escape to LaTeX anywhere in your code (either inside or outside comments), if you use that lexer, as evidenced by the example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\HADOOPUSER}{hduser}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[mathescape]{console}
sudo groupadd #$\HADOOPUSER$
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

An alternative approach  would be to use the `listings` package instead of `minted`. With [some patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137390/21891), escaping to LaTeX can be allowed inside `listings` inline code. If you think that would help, I can expand my answer to provide a solution based on `listings`.

---

**However**. I think it's silly to escape to LaTeX inside inline code. IMO, inline code should be reserved for typesetting a single identifier (keyword, variable, etc.); anything longer than that has the potential to mess up your paragraph. For longer pieces of code (even for a command with arguments such as `sudo groupadd hduser`), you should use a displayed listing instead:

```
\begin{minted}{console}
sudo groupadd hduser
\end{minted}
```

If you follow this rule, you shouldn't need to ever escape to LaTeX inside inline code.

Comment: If hduser is used in multiple places, it does make sense to have a replacement variable.

Comment: @Interfector I agree; code duplication is evil. However, what you want to do is currently not possible with `minted`. You might have better luck with `lstlisting` environments (from the `listings` package).

Answer (score 4):

I am providing a ConTeXt solution, because I do not know about the state of LuaTeX packages in LaTeX.

One possibility is to use Lua  (rather than TeX) to translate your input. For that, ConTeXt provides a `m-translate` module which can be used with the `vim` module. (The `vim` module uses vim to generate syntax highlighting; so, in principal, this should work with minted+LaTeX as well).

```
\usemodule[vim]

\usemodule[translate]
\translateinput[HADOOPUSER][hduser]

\definevimtyping[console][syntax=bash, before=\enableinputtranslation, after=\disableinputtranslation]

\starttext

Translated: \inlineconsole{sudo groupadd HADOOPUSER}

This only works inside console environment, not regular text. For example
HADOOPUSER.


\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

This works as follows: The text `sudo groupadd HADOOPUSER` is written to an external file and translated to `\SYNBOL{}sudo groupadd HADOOPUSER\SYNEOL{}`. When the file is read by TeX, `\enableinputtranslation` is active, so the line is converted to `\SYNBOL{}sudo groupadd hduser\SYNEOL{}` and passed on to TeX, where the macros of `t-vim` add the necessary syntax highlighting.