# How can I correctly break up a ligature in conjunction with glossaries?

Tags: glossaries, babel, ligatures

So for the book to be typeset, we have a glossary created with `glossaries` that contains the word Auflage. The `fl` ligature has to be broken up, because this is a morpheme boundary. So using babel and it's `"|` feature works throughout my document, but in the glossary, there is an issue, see my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{Auflage}{A.}{Auf"|lage}
\begin{document}
    \gls{Auflage} vs. Auf"|lage
    \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

And here is the visual result, where `|"` ends up in the PDF:

[image: Wrong output with glossaries]

Comment: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28437/48973) may also be of interest to you.

Comment: @schtandard, thanks, I was pointed to `selnolig` by @UlrikeFischer before, but short before delivery I want to stay with `pdfLaTeX`. `LuaLaTeX` can be used for the next deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the breaking of the ligature itself, but with the `"` shorthand, which does not work in the `glossaries` macros. You can get around this by just copying the definition of `"|` from `ngermanb.ldf` to a macro:

```latex
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeatletter
  % Definition of "| shorthand copied from ngerman.ldf.
  \def\ligatureseparator{\textormath{\penalty\@M\discretionary{-}{}{\kern.03em}\bbl@allowhyphens}{}}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{Auflage}{A.}{Auf\ligatureseparator lage}

\begin{document}

\gls{Auflage} vs. Auf"|lage
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]