# Change margins locally (for text)

Tags: margins

How can I change margin locally, I mean only in a part i.e. some paragraphs of a page? I've not a list, as in [Changing margins “on the fly”](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-chngmargonfly), but only text. Infact I have to produce for some areas of the page a section with wider margins, while (if I'm nor wrong) `geometry` package,  with command `\newgeometry`, change them for a whole page. thanx

Comment: Please provide a MWE. Perhaps you have heard of `geometry` package and its `\geometry` or `\newgeometry` commands?

Comment: I'm not able to prodyce a MWE for I'm not able to make margins wider in a single section of pagr. Otherwise, my problem would be already solved...

Comment: See [Changing top, bottom, left & right margins on the fly](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68855/5764). The common solution is to use `adjustwidth` from [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage).

Comment: Well your document works so far without changing the margins, am I right? You could drop anything unneeded and that is the base to work with...

Comment: An MWE gives people a base to try out solutions on. Providing it is a courtesy to those who you hope will help you as it saves every one of them having to create a simple document from scratch before they can even begin answering your question. Obviously your MWE won't show how to solve the problem - if it did, you wouldn't be asking in the first place. Rather, it sets up the *problem* you are asking people to solve. All questions should include one - even if it is only the most basic document framework with a couple of lines of text.

Comment: I add a different supplementary code in my MWE, for the general solution in the previous post you refer to is not properly working for my more complex code...

Comment: @user41063 Yes, I see that. That's why MWEs are so important. We could start a process to reopen this question but that might take some time. Perhaps you could then ask a fresh new question, providing right from the beginning the MWE?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Fresh question posted: [Change margin for particular environment (parallel)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171935/5764)