# One paragraph style bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing a research essay for a scholarship that has a two page limit. However, the bibliography spills over onto a third page. I am trying to find a way to make it so that each citation in the bibliography does not start on a new line. This would be sufficient to fit into my page limit.

I am using `natbib`, `bibtex` and `\documentclass{amsart}` but have not found a styling option to compress the bibliography in this manner.

I can give further information, but honestly, do not know what else could be useful in knowing what is out there to solve my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly then my advice would be to make the rest of the document to fit in the limit and leave the bibliography alone. At least don't do what you are suggesting. It is already difficult to read a proper bibliography as it has so many entries. Imagine what it would be to mess with it! Also I don't know if this even an acceptable bibliography style...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Squeeze some more lines on the current page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32112/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple hack (more tweaking is needed to obtain a more usable outcome, in  particular if  the `natbib` `numbers` option is used).

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paralist}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
  {\bibsection\parindent\z@\begin{inparaitem}}
  {\end{inparaitem}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\lipsum 

\cite{test} and \cite{test2}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[Author(1999)]{test} Author (1999). Title. 
\bibitem[Buthor(2000)]{test2} Buthor (2000). Btitle.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]