# Unable to use full use of page in LaTeX

Tags: xetex

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.5cm}
```

[image: A lot of space unused at the end of the page]

- I'm compiling it using XeLeTax
- I tried using `\setlength\footskip{-30pt}` but that hasn't helped

I want to use this free space so that some content on the next page can be push to the previous page itself. Do I have to make changes in the class file? If so, what changes and how?

Comment: Have a look at the [geometry package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) and try something like `\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0mm]{geometry}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Did you try the cm option of the fullpage package?

Answer (score 6):

Here are some suggestions:

1. Instead of using [`fullpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fullpage), use the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to specify your margins. While `fullpage` necessarily sets all the margins to be 1in, you can tighten these using

   ```
   \usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
   ```

   This allows for more content to fit on every page.
2. Try adding `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}` to add 2 more lines on any specific page (at the bottom). See [Squeeze some more lines on the current page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32112/5764).

Answer (score 0):

Try `\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}`. That should give you a 1.5cm margin everywhere, instead of the 1in default (about 1cm extra everywhere).

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to squeeze a given document into as few pages as is possible -- put differently, if your objective is to save as many trees as you can -- you should seriously look into loading the [savetrees](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/savetrees?lang=en) package. If you load it via the instruction

```
\usepackag{savetrees}
```

the following actions will be taken:

- The page margins are set to `1.5cm` -- same as if you specified either `\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}` or `\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}`;
- `\parindent` is set to `1em` -- about one third of the default value;
- `\baselinestretch` is set to `0.95`;
- the distance between the text block and the footnote block is reduced (via `\footskip=2ex`); and
- inter-character and intra-word spacing is also reduced.