# Changing footer margin of one page using fancyhdr

Tags: margins, fancyhdr, footer

I have the following code where I need to put the authors' affiliations in the document footer.  However, the document footer is not large enough for multiple affiliations.  I need to share this template with several others so I need a better answer than resetting the margins throughout the paper. Can I do this using the Fancyhdr package for the footer page style I setup?

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,onecolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{placeins} % added to use float barrier
\usepackage{indentfirst} % indent the first paragraph after the section label

\usepackage[left=3.35cm,right=3.96cm,top=1.905cm,bottom=2.36cm]{geometry}



\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{specialfooter}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}

  \fancyfoot[L]{$^{1}$ \footnotesize{Department of Civil, Construction, and Environmental Engineering, Iowa State University, Ames, IA, USA}  \\
  $^{2}$  \footnotesize{Co-author affiliations, Earth}}

}



\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    {\noindent Title: {\bf \textit{ The Title for an Excellent Work}} }
    \vspace{1\baselineskip}

    % Authors
    {\noindent Authors: \hspace{4ex} Austin Downey$^{1}$ \\}
    {\indent \hspace{10.5ex} Co-author$^{2}$}
    \vspace{1\baselineskip}


\end{titlepage}

\vspace*{8cm}

\thispagestyle{specialfooter}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\section{First section}

\lipsum[1-10]

I do need the large space in the first page.
```

Adding the solution here as I am not sure how long the linked page will be active for.

```
 \fancypagestyle{specialfooter}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \fancyfoot[L]{\footnotesize\smash{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}
   Austin Downey, Dept. of Civil, Construction, and Environmental Eng., Iowa State University, Ames, IA, USA\\
   Co-author, Co-authors affiliation, Earth \\
 \end{tabular}}}
}
```

Comment: `fancyhdr` doesn't touch the layout geometry. It just puts stuff into certain places. You have to make sure there is enough room for that to work. If not, `fancyhdr` prints warnings and tries to change the dimensions, but the result is typically inconsistent layout. At least, that's how it works if `headheight` is too small, say. Off-topic: switches such as `\bf` have been obsolete for LaTeX for 20+ years. Isn't it time to accept that LaTeX-2e is now standard?

Comment: There is no point putting a `\FloatBarrier` at the end of the document, is there?  Nothing can float beyond that point anyway and any floats remaining in the queue will be output at this time. Is the stuff too deep, too high or too wide?

Comment: @cfr, no there is not. That should have been deleted when I removed the rest of the material in the document before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only page of concern is the one dealing with the `specialfooter` change. On that page, you can adjust the allowable text block size through `\enlargethispage{<len>}` (see [Squeeze some more lines on the current page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32112/5764)). Instead of *enlarging* the text block with a positive `<len>`gth, we *shrink* it using a negative `<len>`gth:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage[left=3.35cm,right=3.96cm,top=1.905cm,bottom=2.36cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{specialfooter}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \fancyfoot[L]{\footnotesize\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}
    \textsuperscript{1} Department of Civil, Construction, and Environmental Engineering, Iowa State University, Ames, IA, USA \\
    \textsuperscript{2} Co-author affiliations, Earth
  \end{tabular}}
}

\begin{document}

% Not needed in this minimal example, since it's a stand-alone title page
%\begin{titlepage}
  %\noindent
  %\begin{tabular}{@{} l l }
    %Title: & \bfseries\itshape The Title for an Excellent Work \\
    %\\
    %% Authors
    %Authors: & Austin Downey\textsuperscript{1} \\
             %& Co-author\textsuperscript{2}
  %\end{tabular}
%\end{titlepage}

\vspace*{8cm}% Your title

\thispagestyle{specialfooter}% Special footer for this page
\enlargethispage{-2\baselineskip}% Make text block slightly shorter

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\section{First section}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

You can fiddle around with a different `<len>`gth, depending on your author count.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes more room at the bottom of the page for the author affiliation, however, it does not move the affiliations up so I am still limited on the number of lines that I can have at the bottom.  I was able to get the footer to move up a little bit using \footskip=0 in the fancypagestyle but that only helps so much as I can not set it to negative. I tried changing the text height, \textheight = 500pt ,but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: @AustinDowney: Use `\smash{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}} ... \end{tabular}}` as your footer. That will set it with the last line on the `[b]`aseline of the footer *without* height (due to `\smash`).

Comment: Within fancypagestyle?  If I place it in the main body of the text it does not force itself to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @AustinDowney: [This code](http://pastebin.com/KEjuBct9) produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f2nJ.png). I've added 6 institutions...

Comment: Thanks!  I added the provided code to the question to ensure that it is available in the future for others.