# How to create linearized PDF using TeX?

Tags: pdf, online

Is it possible to create linearized PDFs (optimized for "fast web view") using TeX with free software? (I don't have Acrobat available.)

Comment: It has been deprecated a decade ago, being incompatible with cross-referenced PDF 1.5 — see https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=694099

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *fast web view* is simply a method of allowing content to be displayed as it is being downloaded.

It will not, however, be **fast**. As such the name *fast* can be deviating from its meaning.

You should use [`qpdf --linearize`](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) as noted by @MartinSchroeder (`pdfopt` is deprecated as noted in the comments).

[PDFcrop](http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/) will also do that for you, however with additional work done, i.e. cropping your PDF.

Comment: `pdfopt` does the job. (In Adobe Reader, under properties it now says, "Fast Web View: Yes", that's all I wanted.)

Comment: `pdfopt` is not longer part of ghostscript. Instead of `pdfopt` the `pdfwriter` of `gs` provides an option `-dFastWebView=true`. So you have to use, e.g., `gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFastWebView=true  -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf` instead of `pdfopt`.

Answer (score 31):

Use [`qpdf --linearize`](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/), not `pdfopt`.

`qpdf` uses a pdf library while `pdfopt` uses `ghostscript` and as such has a much larger footprint and is more fragile.

Comment: Would you also tell about the differences between the two tools?

Comment: @AndreyVihrov: done.